# Deep linking android открывать живую активити, если она есть в памяти

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Решаю задачу с deep linking в приложении андроид, по нажатии на ссылку должно открываться приложение и совершаться некоторое действие. В результате нашел решение - для активити в манифесте указывается интент фильтр с нужным доменом и префиксом, в результате чего активити регистрируется на устройстве в качестве способной обрабатывать нажатие на ссылку с определенным доменом, like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="{host}"
                android:pathPrefix="{path_prefix}"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Все работает прекрасно, но я обратил внимание, что открывается новый инстанс этой активити. В этом приложении deep linking используется для авторизации по клику на ссылку из письма. То есть на определенном шаге пользователь сворачивает приложение, открывает почту, кликает по ссылке и получает новый инстанс активити при существующем предыдущем. Чтобы было абсолютно clean надо либо закрывать неубитую активити при нажатии на ссылку, либо открывать не новый инстанс активити, а разворачивать существующий если он есть. Есть ли способ из открывающейся активити произвести такую проверку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, добавить у активити в манифесте параметр `android:launchMode`. Там есть 4 варианта, но вам нужен `singleInstance`. Возможно подойдет `singleTask`. Работает так: если инстанса активити не существует, то создается новый, а если существует, то эта активити просто выталкивается наверх.
Там есть нюанс с получением данных из интента. Бдуте вызван метод `onNewIntent` в котором придет новый интент, запустивший(вытолкнувший) текущий экземпляр активити.

Подробней можно прочитать [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: Мою проблему частично решает, но только частично, потому что я не могу получить данные из интента. getIntent().getData() возвращает null. Пытался ловить в  onStart, onRestart и onResume

Comment: а что на счет `onNewIntent`?

Comment: можно еще просто в методе onNewIntent сделать такое `setIntent(intent);` где `intent` - параметр метода `onNewIntent`